# I can't use curl/curl.h on Raspbian Buster even after installing 4 of its packages

Tags: c++, curl

I am trying to get the content of a URL by using this example: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html

I have installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4
sudo apt-get install libcurlpp-dev
sudo apt-get install libcupt4-2-downloadmethod-curl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I have added that code to a C++ program. The program has a makefile that does not include anything related to `libcurl`. The makefile enables me to use [hzeller's rpi-rgb library](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix):

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter
OBJECTS=Big_ppd_display_try1.o
BINARIES=Big_ppd_display_try1

OPTIONAL_OBJECTS=text_example.o coz_try1.o
OPTIONAL_BINARIES=text_example coz_try1


# Where our library resides. You mostly only need to change the
# RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION, this is where the library is checked out.
RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION=rpi-rgb-led-matrix
RGB_INCDIR=$(RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION)/include
RGB_LIBDIR=$(RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION)/lib
RGB_LIBRARY_NAME=rgbmatrix
RGB_LIBRARY=$(RGB_LIBDIR)/lib$(RGB_LIBRARY_NAME).a
LDFLAGS+=-L$(RGB_LIBDIR) -l$(RGB_LIBRARY_NAME) -lrt -lm -lpthread

all : $(BINARIES)

$(RGB_LIBRARY): FORCE
    $(MAKE) -C $(RGB_LIBDIR)

Big_ppd_display_try1: Big_ppd_display_try1.o  $(RGB_LIBRARY)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Big_ppd_display_try1.o -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(MAGICK_LDFLAGS)

%.o : %.cc
    $(CXX) -I$(RGB_INCDIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Big_ppd_display_try1.o : Big_ppd_display_try1.cc
    $(CXX) -I$(RGB_INCDIR) $(CXXFLAGS) $(MAGICK_CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(BINARIES) $(OPTIONAL_OBJECTS) $(OPTIONAL_BINARIES)

FORCE:
.PHONY: FORCE
```

And I have an `undefined reference` to all of the `libcurl` functions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/4panel $ sudo make all
make -C rpi-rgb-led-matrix/lib
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/www/html/4panel/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/lib'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/www/html/4panel/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/lib'
g++ -Wall -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter Big_ppd_display_try1.o -o Big_ppd_display_try1 -Lrpi-rgb-led-matrix/lib -lrgbmatrix -lrt -lm -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: Big_ppd_display_try1.o: in function `main':
/var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:240: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:243: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:246: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:249: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:252: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:255: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:262: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:265: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:272: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/usr/bin/ld: /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1.cc:274: undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:24: Big_ppd_display_try1] Error 1
```

I am using Visual Studio Code on a Linux PC to check the code for errors and to debug and I have no errors or warnings there.

The code is identical to the one in the libcurl example, with the exception that it is all in a big `while(true)` loop, because I need it to run indefinitely as a process on a Raspberry Pi 4.

What do you think ?

Comment: @Botje Is this supposed to help ? Because I don't get it.

Comment: Your compile command is missing `-lcurl`. The linked question explains what is going on.

Comment: I have no idea what to do with `-lcurl`. And I don't want to use flags. My compile command is `sudo make all`, just like I did before adding this new code.

Comment: Add `-lcurl` to the line that starts with `LDFLAGS+=`

Comment: @Botje, thank you ! It works. Man, I hate makefiles.